# Vuetify: Maintain checkbox selection after changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-list with a checkbox in each v-list-item. Whenever I make changes, the checkbox selection gets disappeared.

In the below code when I click the "change Value" button, one of the value in the "items" arrays get changed. During that time the checkbox selection gets disappeared. But in the "fieldSelection" array, the value still exists. How to maintain the selection even after the changes.

code Pen: https://codepen.io/eajithkumar128/pen/RwrdrEg?editors=1010

```
       <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-item-title class="caption inputText--text pl-1">
            {{item.text}}
            <span
              class="pl-1"
  
            >({{item.value}})</span>
          </v-list-item-title>
            <v-checkbox
            v-model="fieldSelection"
            :value="item.value"
            color="primary"
            multiple
            hide-details
            dense
          />
              <v-list-item-title class="caption inputText--text pl-1">
            {{item.text}}
            <span
              class="pl-1"
  
            >({{item.value}})</span>
          </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      <v-btn class="mx-15" @click="changeValue" color="primary">change Value</v-btn>
      {{ fieldSelection }}
```

```
data: () => ({
    item: 1,
    fieldSelection:[],
    items: [
      { value:"0",text: 'Real-Time', icon: 'mdi-clock' },
      { value:"1",text: 'Audience', icon: 'mdi-account' },
      {value:"2", text: 'Conversions', icon: 'mdi-flag' },
    ],
  }),
  methods:{
    changeValue(){
      let selection = this.fieldSelection;
      this.fieldSelection.forEach(v=>{
        this.items[v].value = "5"
      })
      console.log(selection)
      this.fieldSelection = selection
    }
  }
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve and what's happening

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Brahim I have "Items" Array through which I populate the "v-list". This list has a checkbox associated with it. Consider I am selecting a few checkboxes and performing an action to change the value of the "items" array, the checkbox selection gets disappeared. I want to maintain the selections even if the "items" array value gets changed. In the code pen provided try to select any change checkbox and. change the value the selection will get disappeared.

Comment: does [this](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/bGEZEPx?editors=1010) respond to your use case?